# acts_as_votable thumbs up/down buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voting, social-media-like

I installed the acts_as_votable gem, it works in the console like it should (like it says in the documentation).
So my question is how to set up a form for upvote and downvote buttons? or can they simply be links?

here is the documentation: github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/master/README.markdown

I have a user and a picture model; the user is supposed to be able to like the picture. 
code from the picture view, where the buttons should be:

```
<% for picture in @pictures %> 
<p> 
<%= image_tag picture.image_url(:thumb).to_s %> 
</p> 
<%= picture.created_at.strftime("%a, %d %b. %Y") %>, by 
<%= link_to picture.user.name, picture.user %> 
<h2> <%= link_to picture.name, picture %></h2> 

[buttons here] 

<%= picture.votes.size %> <% end %>
```

Comment: honestly, I have no idea how to set a form like this up.
here is the documentation: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/master/README.markdown
I have a user and a picture model; the user is supposed to be able to like the picture.

code from the picture view, where the buttons should be:
<% for picture in @pictures %>
<p>
<%=  image_tag picture.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
</p>
<%= picture.created_at.strftime("%a, %d %b. %Y") %>, by
<%= link_to picture.user.name, picture.user %>
<h2> <%= link_to picture.name, picture %></h2>

[buttons here]

<%= picture.votes.size %>
<% end %>

Comment: Ok. Add that to your original question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do this is to add your own controller actions for up- and downvotes.
I'm assuming you have a `current_user` method available in your controller.

```
# pictures_controller.rb
def upvote
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  @picture.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to @picture
end

def downvote
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  @picture.downvote_from current_user
  redirect_to @picture
end

# config/routes.rb

resources :pictures do
  member do
    put "like", to: "pictures#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "pictures#downvote"
  end
end

# some view

<%= link_to "Upvote", like_picture_path(@picture), method: :put %>
<%= link_to "Downvote", dislike_picture_path(@picture), method: :put %>
```

Comment: There's a typo in the view code; `method: :put` needs to be passed to `link_to`, not the path helper. Cheers :).

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I ended up doing it with the acts_as_commentable gem too. So I think this should work with any object that you have comments for.

In my _comment.html.erb view

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", {:controller =>"comments", :action => "upvote", :id => comment.id}, :class => 'btn', method: :put %>
<%= link_to "Downvote", {:controller =>"comments", :action => "downvote", :id => comment.id}, :class => 'btn', method: :put %>
```

in my routes.rb file

```
put '/comments/:id/:action' => 'comments#upvote'
put '/comments/:id/:action' => 'comments#downvote'
```

Then in my comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_commentable
  before_filter :find_comment, :only => [:upvote, :downvote]



  def upvote
    current_user.upvotes @comment
    redirect_to(@comment.commentable)
  end

  def downvote
    @comment.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to(@comment.commentable)
  end




private

  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

  def find_comment
    @comment = Comment.find(@commentable.id)
  end


end
```

The before filters allow for more versatility so I can add this to any commentable object. Mine happened to be festivals, but you could do pictures or anything really. Check out the acts_as_commentable documentation and the polymorphic railscast for more information on that. This is my first post so if this is terrible code, just tell me.