# Ruby on Rails Rating/Liking Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rating, rate, rating-system

i'm searching Days now for a Rate/Like Gem that allows me to rate/like an image just like the Facebook Like.
I'm having that button hovering over my image:

[image]

and it would be nice if could access the Like Count and Display it.
I would not post this if i didn't really searched it, but after DAYS, maybe someone knows a quick solution to my Problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried `acts_as_votable` gem? if no, that's what you need

Usage:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  acts_as_votable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  acts_as_voter
end
```

Helpful links

- https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#likedislike-yesno-updown
- [acts_as_votable thumbs up/down buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012276/acts-as-votable-thumbs-up-down-buttons)

Comment: Hey Thanks, it really seems that's it. Do you have any experience with this gem because im getting some odd problems and im kinda new to rails .

Comment: Sure, if you have any problem feel free to ask)

Comment: Thanks :), so i added the Gem and the acts_as relations to my models (Users, Pins). If i understood this correctly i need only to add do my User model acts_as_voter and to my Pin model acts_as_votable, Correct?

Comment: Cool, but from there i'm lost. How do i get the Like action. I have a button but what is the link? <%= @pin.what? %>

Comment: You need to add this buttons manually, Here is best explanation how to add up/down buttons to `acts_as_votable` gem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012276/acts-as-votable-thumbs-up-down-buttons

Comment: Cool, i got it from here. Not getting it right just now but you gave me enough Staff to Study. Thanks Talgat :)