# Acts as votable routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use acts as votable gem and can't understand how it actually works. I couldn't find any good workarounds or tutorials for it. I tried implementing the accepted solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15027717/1936710) but got Routing Error. Can anyone help me out with a good tutorial or point me out how to get it to work editing the following code.

routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
  end
end
```

posts controller

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to @post
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Bookmark Post", like_post_path(@post, method: :put), class: "button tiny" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`method` attribute should be passed to the `link_to` method, not the path helper, like this

```
<%= link_to "Bookmark Post", like_post_path(@post), method: :put, class: "button tiny" %>
```

Comment: thank you...can you please mention this to the post I mentioned so that beginners like me don't get confused. I have yet to get the reputation to comment there.