# Voting for nested objects using Acts as Votable gem in a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

Using this answer [Voting for nested objects using the Acts As Votable gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390120/voting-for-nested-objects-using-the-acts-as-votable-gem) I was able to get voting working for my app but not exactly what I was hoping for. In Carl's example his "dish" model belongs_to :dish_category but my setup looks more like this:

```
 class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :restaurants, through: :dish_categories
 end
```

Right now when someone votes for a dish, it counts as a vote for that dish regardless of the restaurant. I would like to figure out if it's possible for dishes to have separate voting counts based on current restaurant. So if I'm a user I can vote up pizza at one restaurant but then vote down pizza at a different restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after getting a bit more data together, I think I have a solution that, although seemingly complicated, it's simple really and organized.

I would suggest that you have your Restaurant and Dish models, as well as your DishRestaurant join table (or DishCategories as you have it in your original post), and finally a VoteContainer to hold the logic for votes.

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dish_restaurants
  has_many :dishes, through: :dish_restaurants
end

class Dish < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :dish_restaurants
  has_many :restaurants, through: :dish_restaurants

  def votes
    dish_restaurants.vote_container 
  end
end

class DishRestaurant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dish
  belongs_to :restaurant

  has_one :vote_container
end

class VoteContainer < ApplicationRecord
  act_as_votable
  belongs_to :dish_restaurant
end
```

I was thinking of something along these lines may work.  In theory, dish.votes should be your gateway to the logic for managing votes

---

### Original Reply  (disregard)

So, what I'm thinking is you may have what may feel like duplicate dishes.  So, you'll create a new pizza dish for each restaurant that offers pizza.  Technically it's not a duplicate, as it has it's own vote count for that particular restaurant.  This would probably be the easiest and most sensible way from what you're currently presenting.

This makes sense also because not every restaurant makes pizza the same way as others.  Each pizza may have different attributes (price, ingredients, etc).  If you do it the way I've suggested, you'll be open to these p

Comment: Of course that would be easier - but that would change the requirements I have. There is other functionality that requires that "pizza" remain intact as one dish. For instance, one dish that can appear in a multisearch - so you don't get countless results for pizza when searching - you get one result in case a user wants to see all the restaurants serving pizza.

Comment: Also - my app isn't actually a restaurant/dish app - I'm just using this as an example. Just imagine that all pizza is the same in every restaurant and costs the same.

Comment: Perhaps have another model that belongs to the dish, the restaurant, and holds your votes.

Comment: Good point - if my version of "dish_categories" (using this linked example) is set up already so that it belongs to the dish and the restaurant, would that model work or do you advise just keeping that separate and using a completely new model?

Comment: Technically, yes, you can. However, it goes against some conventions. Give me a moment to edit my post for a more detailed answer that I would suggest.

Updated my post.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: I think this is going to work but I can't figure out why I'm getting this error: undefined method `vote_container' for #<Grouping::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f8ab552a368> in my "dish" model whenever I am looking at a "restaurant" where I have a restaurant's dishes listed.

Comment: Same error when accessing the dish view with dish.votes